# "If the input is alphanumeric characters..." or "If the input are alphanumeric characters..."

Tags: grammar, phrases, tenses

Seeing how the subject of the sentence "input" is singular I initially opted for "If the input is alphanumeric characters..." but it sounds a bit strange.

Could someone explain which are the rules that should be applied in this kind of sentences?

Comment: Just drop *characters*. "If the input is alphanumeric, [...]". Otherwise, you need something like "if the input consists of alphanumeric characters, [...]" or "if the input is comprised of alphanumeric characters, [...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there is one input and that one input contains many characters.

You should consider using 'contains', 'consists of' or 'made up of':

"If the input consists of alphanumeric characters..."

In the same way you wouldn't say "if the team is men", but rather "if the team is made up of men".

Comment: Does that mean that it's just wrong to compose a phrase in such a way?

Comment: An alternative without changing the words in use... "if the input characters are alphanumeric"